# Jcomponents getName

Tags: java, json, swing, reflection, jcombobox

how to get JComponent name(JComboBox,JCheckBox,JTextComponent...etc)
 how i can get fieldName for put this name to HashMap, for example:

```
       HashMap<String,String> map;
    public HashMap<String,String> getHash(){
    map = new HashMap();
    ArrayList<JCombobox> list = className.getCombobox();
    for(int index=0;index<list.size();index++){
     map.putt(list.get(index).getName , list.get(index).getSelectedItem());
     }
   return map;
 }
```

getName returns "null"
i have large form for component.setName("name") method.... plz help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the name attribute of a component is not set so this must be done explicitly before [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29) will return a value. The simplest way is to do this manually before the `JCombobox` are added to the `List`, e.g.

```
for (int i=0; i < COMBO_COUNT; i++) {
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setName("combo" + (i + 1));
    list.add(comboBox);
}
```

Comment: how do this automatically?)) form has over 40 different components comonentns, thats over 80 code lines.

Comment: Reflection, but note that reflection is often considered the right answer to the wrong question.  That right question being, what are you trying to achieve through this?

Comment: I think it's simpler to do this manually, e.g. using a for loop

Comment: by that hashMap i create Json and transfer that to server for sql query.

Comment: or get/putClientProperty instead of HashMap